# postgres 9.1 master-master setup using Bucardo

Tags: postgresql, master-master

is anyone aware of any comprehensive tutorials for setting up 2 postgres 9.1 databases in master-master configuration? 
What "add-ons" are required (for example is Bucardo still a necessity?). I have tried googling but a lot of posts that I find are dated back a couple of years so I am not sure if they are still relevant.Let me be more specific:

For example the following approach might be effective: - install bucardo on master1 - setup replication as follows: master1: master - master2: slave - verify that replication works If the above are correct then: - install bucardo on master2 - setup replication as follows: master2: master - master1: slave - verify replication works Will the previous be enough or I am missing a fundamental piece here?

Below is the advise I got from the bucardo mailing list - perhaps this will be useful to someone:

"Bucardo only needs to be installed on one host, although obviously, that won't provide HA capability. Typically, in a master-master scenario, it's installed on one of the masters. In the event either of the masters then goes down, the Bucardo daemon wouldn't have anything to do anyway, so HA for it is pretty moot."

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: I have tried setting up Bucardo on one host, do I need to setup Bucardo in both hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bucardo only needs to be installed on one host, although obviously, that won't provide HA capability. Typically, in a master-master scenario, it's installed on one of the masters. In the event either of the masters then goes down, the Bucardo daemon wouldn't have anything to do anyway, so HA for it is pretty moot.

Some useful links:

http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/bootstrap-bucardo-mulitmaster.html

http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/06/bucardo-multi-master-for-postgresql.html